# How to get the raw content of a hash with jq?

Tags: jq

Given the following:

```
> echo '{"thing":{"one":1,"two":2,"three":3}}'|jq .thing
{
  "one": 1,
  "two": 2,
  "three": 3
}
```

How do I get the command to output that?

```
"one": 1
"two": 2
"three": 3
```

Comment: I thought 'jq .thing[]' would do it, but that only returns the values of each key for me.

Answer (score 3):

Convert the object to entries first then generate the strings.  Just make sure you get the raw output.

```
$ ... | jq -r '.thing | to_entries[] | "\(.key | tojson): \(.value)"'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that uses `-r` and **keys_unsorted**:

```
$ echo '{"thing":{"one":1,"two":2,"three":3}}' \
| jq -r '.thing | keys_unsorted[] as $k | "\"\($k)\": \(.[$k])"'
```

which produces the following output:

```
"one": 1
"two": 2
"three": 3
```